# MySQL Relational friends scheme?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how you'd work a PHP and MySQL Friends system?
I was thinking like, in the `users` table there would be a colum titled `friends` which would hold data with other user IDs who they are friends with seperated by commas,
for example, `1,3,56,3` - then explode this and foreach the array?
Would that work?

Comment: yes [12 more characters]

Comment: It would work, but you shouldn't do it that way. Make a separate table for friendships.

Answer (score 6):

That is one way to do it.
You may want to consider creating a new row for each friend.

For example:

Friend ID: 1
Friend Name: Bob

Friend ID: 2
Friend Name: Ron

Friend ID: 3
Friend Name: Joe

If Bob was friends with both Ron and Joe there would be 2 records in the friends table

```
id  user  friend  
1   1     2  
2   1     3
```

Then if joe became friends with bob but not ron the table would end up being

```
id  user  friend  
1   1     2  
2   1     3  
3   3     1
```

This gives you flexibility down the road to add in more complex queries.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it as comma-separated strings, have a user_friends table with each friend relationship as a record. A comma-separated string isn't going to be usefully indexable or queryable.

Comment: Would I use two columns like `user1` and `user2` then when getting the friends loop through the database and check whether either of them is the current users id?

Answer (score 0):

Important example:

Friend 1 is connected with Friend 2
You have to lookup the user_id AND the friend_id to find all the friends of Friend 1